# to access cell renderers in a row in AG Grid react

Tags: ag-grid-react

I am using cell renderers in two columns of react AG Grid. Both of them provides input component where I can type. Based on what I type in the input field of one cell renderer, the input field in the second cell renderer, in the same row need to be disabled.
I am not able to access and disable the input field of second cell renderer when I change value of the input field of the first cell renderer.

How can I access all the cell renderer's in a specfic row and handle their props. I am using functional components

Comment: Add more tags, like the programming language and framework that you are using. That way, more relevant people will see your question.